# Android multiline edittext not increasing its height as the user types

Tags: android, height, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, multiline

So the layout is quite simple. A `ListView` occupying most of the screen, and a `RelativeLayout` at the bottom containing the `EditText` and a `Button` to the right. Everything looks great, but the problem is that as the user types and enters new lines, the `EditText` is not increasing its height just enough so that the user can see all the text types without scrolling. You would think that using `WRAP_CONTENT` on both the `EditText` and its parent `RelativeLayout` would take care of that, but it doesn't for some reason. Any ideas? Here's the Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/postCommentRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewCommentsPostCommentButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="@string/post" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/viewCommentsInsertCommentTextEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewCommentsPostCommentButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/viewCommentsPostCommentButton"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_comment"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/entriesListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/postCommentRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false" >

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in the end I couldn't figure it out. Instead, I used a `LinearLayout` instead of the `RelativeLayout` in the nested Layout. Here's the new Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/postCommentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/viewCommentsInsertCommentTextEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_comment"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewCommentsPostCommentButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/post" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/entriesListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/postCommentLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false" >

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `maxlines` property, perhaps.